According to quran 2:216 should one change his course if it's not helping him even if he's passionate about it?
It's been 4 years and I'm in a continuous rut. Put my efforts, do a little than due to interruption coming by any means I lose the flow. Was studying Software Engineering in university being granted the opportunity last time to continue without the fee for the semester which I left previously than it just happened by luck that my foot got fractured. Though I kept visiting uni after a little improvement gave mids, cleared them but just but due to distractions again got frowned ending up losing the last chance. I had complaints with my parents that despite knowing my psychological condition you decided to shift to the far away area knowing that I wouldn't be able to manage. They allowed me to withdraw semester from the most expensive university and acted upon my proposal. They fixed it but I left again they tried every effort that I by any means graduate and settle but I left and they forgave me. My father got me hired up in a job, I left. I don't know why but I'm not willing to accept failure of being lagging behind. I announced that I won't be continuing there I will study though they were not happy with it and now I'm enrolled in a Virtual University. I'm trying to fix up. Say my prayers, abstain from evil desires. Humbled myself before Lord cried multiple times sought repentance. I try to start but get  perplexed. Lack directions, clear guidance any motivation. I acknowledge I failed as a son. I just don't know what to do as a last resort. My father have left 6 months from job and the contract will finish. Our only source of income and currently under debt. I wanna apologize to them but I lack courage. I don't know how to proceed further. Whether circumstances would go in favour or not. Struggling through OCD for 7 years. Facing related complications from this as well. Suffer through mental pain when in washroom leading me sometimes to complain Lord and think blasphemous. I don't know if it ain't fixing or I myself ain't fixing it up. Time is ticking. I fear ending up like doing nothing.

I'm gonna be 24 by September. My batch passed out and even the next batch.
